# Case-sensitive error in compiler's building using crosstool-ng under Cygwin

Tags: windows-7, linux, cygwin, compile

When I try to build gcc cross-compiler using crosstool-ng under Cygwin (running in Windows 7) I have the following message:

```
$ /opt/ng-crosstool/bin/ct-ng build
[INFO ]  Performing some trivial sanity checks
[ERROR]  Your file system in '/devdir/.build' is *not* case-sensitive!
[00:02] / make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I try to add in \etc\fstab (as recommend [here](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html)):

```
C:/forbuild /forbuild ext3 binary,posix=1
```

but it doesn't help
However, when i run mount command i have the following result:

```
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto)
C:/forbuild on /forbuild type ntfs (binary)
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto)
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
D: on /cygdrive/d type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

What's the problem? How i can use crosstool-ng in Cygwin?

Comment: Did you set the registry key as described in the User's Guide? Have you tested you can indeed create both files FOO and foo on the mounted path in question? If you look at the configure script or whatever's doing the sanity check, how does it actually do the checking?